# Should my scripts send email in text/plain instead of text/html?

Tags: php, email, content-type

I can do so much more in an email with a `text/html` content type.

Comment: What part of this question is specific to programming?

Comment: The biggest benefit is that I will be able to actually read it when its text/plain because I have disabled text/html mails in my client ;)

Comment: @BoltClock, Content type in the context of the question is a concept developed by programmers, isn't it? I figured if someone could answer the question, that would be the programmers. I apologize if I did wrong by posting it here.

Comment: @Emanuil: This is not a programming question the way you've put it. Try something like "Should my scripts send email in text/plain instead of text/html? What are the advantages/disadvantages?" You should at least mention code/scripting/programming once in your question. ;)

Comment: You should *always* send a plain text alternative along with your HTML variant. Because just like @Gordon I prefer the plain text variant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all e-mail authoring tools support HTML markup.  They should not send text/html if that is not what it was intended to be.

MIME types such as text/plain and text/html go beyond e-mails.  They describe how content should be interpreted (by web browsers, mail clients, etc).  If there's no markup on the data provided by the author (i.e., it is intended to be rendered as plain text), then text/plain is very useful for that (has been and always will be).

**EDIT:** You have [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4759716/revisions) your question a few times since I wrote this answer.  To answer your latest version of the question, you should support text/plain if you want to allow your users the option of sending mail as plain text.  Some people (such as me) prefer it.  We don't like the un-necessary extra traffic and we don't like clients attempting to render it in any way but plain text (to preserve text-based formatting, like line breaks, spaces, tabs, etc).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the multiple changes. I got carried away a little bit. Thanks for the very informative answer!